# How do I use regex to remove any non alpha characters after last alpha character in string?

Tags: javascript, regex

So the rule I would like to apply to clean the strings I have is:

Search for last character in that has a letter between A-Z/i and remove all characters after it. Like this:

```
"WASHER," -> "WASHER" (R is last alpha character)
"VALVE,NEEDLE," -> "VALVE,NEEDLE" (E is last alpha character)
"HOSE,HYDRAULIC. 3466" -> "HOSE,HYDRAULIC" (C is last alpha character)
"WASHER . " -> "WASHER" (R is last alpha character)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, by using: [^A-Z]+$

```js
console.log("WASHER,".replace(/[^A-Z]+$/,""))
console.log("VALVE,NEEDLE,".replace(/[^A-Z]+$/,""))
console.log("HOSE,HYDRAULIC. 3466".replace(/[^A-Z]+$/,""))
console.log("WASHER . ".replace(/[^A-Z]+$/,""))
```